# Why deploy Kerberos for Exchange 2010 SP1 RU3?

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010, kerberos, ntlm, spn

The first version of Exchange 2010 to support Kerberos is SP1 RU3.  It does this through the `RollAlternateServiceAccountCredential.ps1` commandlet.

> Besides implementing "better" security, does this offer any other benefits for disaster recovery, performance, or anything else worth knowing?

FYI - in case Google sends you here:

The way to determine if Kerberos is being used, use `KList.exe` in conjunction with

```
Test-OutlookConnectivity -Identity administrator -MailboxCredential $c -Protocol tcp
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By my read of it, this will provide two things:

1. If you're using a CAS Array, clients will authenticate faster since they won't have to fail-back past Kerberos to NTLM anymore.
2. Kerberos is generally considered more secure than NTLM, so overall security should be improved.

I don't believe it offers any benefits to disaster recovery, just initial-connection performance and possibly reduced log-spam.